# Add a static library (.a file) to React Native iOS project

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a React Native iOS project. There is a 3rd party SDK I would like to use. That SDK is published as a static library (`.a` file) and a header file (`.h` file).

My approach has been.

1. Create new folder in the `/Libraries` directory. Add the `.a` and `.h` files to that new directory.
2. Drag the `.a` file into `Link Binary With Libraries`

However, when I build the app it throws the error:

```
Library not found for -INameOfSDK
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double-check that the library is matched your app architecture.
`lipo -info PATH_TO_LIBRARY`